# Running only one single test with CMake + make

Tags: testing, cmake

If I have a bunch of tests for my project, I can run them - after `cmake`ing and `make`ing to build, building - with `make test`.

But what if I only want to run one of my tests? That is, one of the items for which I have a `add_test()` in the tests `CMakeFile.txt` ?

Comment: [Instead of `ConfigureTest` you mean `add_test`, aren't you?] For run a single test, execute `ctest` directly with appropriate parameters. E.g. `ctest -R <test-name>`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Yes, that was a macro which we have in our project. Edited.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**tl;dr** - Do this:

```
cd $YOUR_BUILD_DIRECTORY
ctest -R name_of_your_test
```

### Explanation

Here is how you likely got confused:

1. You were trying to do this with `make`, since `make test` runs all the tests for you. This won't work for a single test (although there's a workaround - see @danger89's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65164688/1593077)). [`ctest`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/ctest/Testing-With-CTest) is the cross-platform way to do it.
2. You started using `ctest`, e.g. in your main project directory, and you probably got something like:

   ```
    *********************************
    No test configuration file found!
    *********************************
    Usage

      ctest [options]
   ```

   which wasn't helpful.
3. ... So you thought "Ok, maybe `ctest` has a `-C` switch, like CMake and GNU Make" - and indeed, it has a `-C` switch! but that didn't do what you expected:

   ```
    [joeuser:/home/joeuser/src/myproj]$ ctest -C build
    Test project /home/joeuser/src/myproj
    No tests were found!!!
   ```

What you actually need to do:

```
  cd $YOUR_BUILD_DIRECTORY
  ctest -R name_of_your_test
```

(note that `-R` matches a regular expression.) This should work. Note that you can *list* the tests to be run rather than actually run them by passing `-N` to `ctest`.

---

<sub>* Thanks goes to @RTsyvarev for pointing me in the right direction
* If your test's name is also the prefix of another test name, use `ctest -R '^name_of_your_test$'` - the argument is actually a regex.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

einpoklum is not fully correct. Actually you can use `make test` if you like. CMake will generate a Makefile and I found out that it accepts an `ARGS` variable.

Meaning you are able run specific tests via for example the -R (regex) parameter. Which will look like this when using make test:

```
make test ARGS="-R '^test_'"
```

This will run only the testcases files that starts with `test_` in their filename.

*Note:* `-R` above is just an example, it will accept **all** the arguments that `ctest` command will accept as well.

Anyway the make test example above will do exactly the same as running:

```
ctest -R '^test_'
```