# ninja run specific test

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, ninja

My CMake project builds several targets that add units tests using

```
project(my_test)

add_test(
    NAME name
    COMMAND command)
```

The selected generator for this project is ninja.
Once built I can run all the tests from the command line using

```sh
ninja test
```

The output neatly lists all tests run as expected and their results.

But I wonder, can I specify - via arguments - which test(s) to run from the command line?
Possibly by the test's given name, target name or otherwise?

Ninja's help states (excerpt):

```sh
usage: ninja [options] [targets...]
```

So I have tried putting

```sh
ninja test my_test
```

Hoping to filter in only those tests added by the given target.
But still it seemingly runs all tests across all targets.

Additional info:

This is a Qt project. When I load the project into Qt Creator I can hand select which tests to run.
It would be a boon to be able to do the same from the command line via `ninja` or other.

Comment: A target `test` runs all tests unconditionally. For selectively run tests, run them via [ctest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html).

Comment: @Tsyvarev So simple. Why couldn't I find this answer on the internet? Looking in the wrong places. Many thanks. Turn yours into an answer and I will accept.

Comment: "Why couldn't I find this answer on the internet?" - Probably, you have used wrong wording for search. Googling for "cmake run specific test" got me the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160415/running-only-one-single-test-with-cmake-make) at the first position.